# MVVM WPF Image dependencyProperties dont seem to do anything after Binding the Height of the parent

Tags: c#, wpf, image, mvvm

As mentioned in the title, I have a strange problem i cant explain.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ShownPictureItems, Mode=OneWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top">

                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <UniformGrid Columns="{Binding PictureColumns, Mode=OneWay}" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>

                        <Button Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=MaterialDesignFlatButton}" Height="{Binding PictureHeight}" Margin="5" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                            Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:PictureOverviewView}},
                                                Path=DataContext.SelectPictureCommand, Mode=OneTime}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding}" >

                            <material:Card Background="White" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                <Image Stretch="UniformToFill" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">                                        
                                    <Image.Source>
                                        <BitmapImage DecodePixelHeight="200" CacheOption="OnLoad" UriSource="{Binding Path}" />
                                    </Image.Source>
                                </Image>
                            </material:Card>
                        </Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
```

The mentioned problem arises in this line:

```
<Image Stretch="UniformToFill" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
```

When I bind the Height of the button to the viewModel, the properties of the image get ignored. The image gets neither stretched, nor aligned. When I simply write Height="300" everything works like a charm. I need to control the Height of the button, to scale the buttons, for when I want to show more or less buttons.

the ItemControl binds to an observableCollection.

I hope someone can help me. I'm new to WPF and MVVM.

Edit: I found the solution, after looking closely at the output window

the Height Binding should be like this:

```
Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:PictureOverviewView}},
                                                Path=DataContext.PictureHeight}"
```

in my first version it was looking for the PictureHight in the ShownPictureItems observableCollection, which consists of Pictures. After it did not find that property, it defaultet

Comment: As a test, give the button an `x:Name=""` and change the height property via the code behind file (`MyWindow.xaml.cs`), I suspect it has something to do with the changing of the property after the image has already rendered.

Comment: Does the output window say anything on the subject?

Comment: the output window says:
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'PictureHeight' property not found on 'object' ''Picture' (HashCode=45890209)'. BindingExpression:Path=PictureHeight; DataItem='Picture' (HashCode=45890209); target element is 'Button' (Name=''); target property is 'Height' (type 'Double')

the strange thing is, I can change the Height of the button with this code like intended.

Comment: BindingExpression path error: '**PictureHeight**' property not found on 'object' ''**Picture**' (HashCode=45890209)'.  So, where's the code for **Picture.PictureHeight**?  It doesn't exist in your question.  Post the code in an [edit].  My WAG is that the property's name is "PictureHieght" or a similar misspelling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, after looking closely at the output window

the Height Binding should be like this:

```
Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:PictureOverviewView}},
                                                Path=DataContext.PictureHeight}"
```

in my first version it was looking for the PictureHight in the ShownPictureItems observableCollection, which consists of Pictures. After it did not find that property, it defaultet